# 'It is impossible' followed by a that-clause vs. 'It is impossible' followed by a for + Noun Phrase + to + Infinitive construction

Tags: sentence-meaning, subordinate-clauses, to-infinitive

*It is impossible that everyone is telling the truth.*

*It is impossible for everyone to be telling the truth.*

What on earth is the difference between the meanings of two sentences above?

Comment: Semantically (meaning-wise), they are the same.

Comment: The 2nd sentence implies ***more skepticism*** about the truthfulness of the situation.

Comment: As explained, there is a difference in meaning. There is also a big difference in the grammar.

Answer (score 0):

> It is impossible that Joe, at age 5 and at only 1 meter in height, is dunking the basketball.
>
> It is impossible for Joe, at age 5 and at only 1 meter in height, to be dunking the basketball.

The first makes a statement about something that is not possible: "Joe ... is dunking the basketball".

The second makes a statement about something that is not possible for Joe to be doing: "for Joe ... to be dunking the basketball".

So if there's any nuanced difference, a whisper of a difference, it is that the second locates the impossibility in the person of Joe a tad more forcefully than the first.